# Markdown syntax for table in Jupyter PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, markdown, jupyter

I'm trying to use Jupyter in PyCharm. It is nice what JetBrains have done. I'm writing some markdown in a cell but the table is not rendering as it should.

```
# This is Markdown code

Item|Description
---|----
Item 1|Some description

|Item|Description|
|---|----|
|Item 1|Some description|

- Item 1
- Item 2

**Gilberto Diaz**

*Gilberto Diaz*

[Google](www.google.com)
```

[image]

Everything renders but tables.Does anyone know the syntax to render tables in this environment before I open a ticket in JetBrains?

Comment: Tables are non-standard Markdown and various different styles of syntax for them exist. It could be you need a different style (alter your syntax) or you need to enable them (they are off by default) or they are simply not supported at all (which would not necessarily be a bug). Have you checked the documentation for the Markdown implementation you are using?

Comment: I have installed Markdown Navigator, Markdown support and gfh. These are plugins for Pycharm.

Comment: @Gilbert did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Poulad I write markdown in vscode and the actual code in PyCharm.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to make a table. Use this in Markdown and tailor it to your need.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
    <th>Heading 3</th> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Replace</td> 
    <td>Replace</td> 
    <td>Replace</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Replace</td> 
    <td>Replace</td> 
    <td>Replace</td>   
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: It's valid syntax according to every markdown syntax specification I know of. I think you mean to say that it's not the syntax typically used as an extension to markdown, based on ||. That is however not part of the core Markdown spec, although it is part of github flavored markdown (GFM) with wide support by tools etc.Ironically what you think of as "markdown table syntax" is not part of markdown, however this example which you consider to not be markdown is.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/hub/Markdown-Syntax.html#quick-notes-markdown-tables you can use the following syntax:

```
Month | Assignee | Backup
---:|:---:| ---
**January** | Dave | _Steve_
**February** | Gregg | _Karen_
**March** | Diane | _Jorge_
```

Which as of the `Professional 2020.2` version, render as follows:

[image]